# How to sort data in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

I have a `QTableWidget` and the first column contains numbers from 1 to 1000. Now I need to sort the table based on this first column.

I'm using the function `sortItems(int column, Qt::AscendingOrder)`, but it is displayed as:

> 1, 10, 100, 1000, 101, 102, ...

Yet I need this result:

> 1, 2, 3 ,4...., 1000.

I'm using a CSV file for populating the table.

Comment: That isn't a question.  It is a noun phrase with a question mark.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to subclass QTableWidgetItem and then implement the < operator to be smart about the fact that you're sorting numbers and not strings.

```
class MyTableWidgetItem : public QTableWidgetItem {
    public:
        bool operator <(const QTableWidgetItem &other) const
        {
            return text().toInt() < other.text().toInt();
        }
};
```

Then when you're populating your table you can pass it instances of your custom items that know how to sort themselves properly instead of the generic ones.

Comment: Thanks, this works. In newer versions of Qt, the signature has changed slighly to `bool operator< ( const QTableWidgetItem & other ) const`

Comment: Seriously, if `setData(Qt::DisplayRole, num)` doesn't work for you, you should try this.

Answer (score 29):

The values are sorted as strings because you stored them as such in the model.

The `QVariant` can remember the original type of the data if you let it do the conversion itself, and the comparison operator from that type will be used when sorting:

```
// Get the value from the CSV file as a numeric type
int valueFromCsvFile = ...;

// don't do this
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(valueFromCsvFile));

// but do this instead
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
item.setData(Qt::EditRole, valueFromCsvFile);
```

The cell editor will also adapt to the type of the QVariant:

- `QSpinBox` for `int`,
- `QDoubleSpinBox` for `double` and `float`,
- `QDateTimeEdit` for `QDateTime`
- ...

Comment: I used 'item.setData(Qt::EditRole, valueFromCsvFile)' and now its working fine.

Thanks!!

Comment: @Shyam, why not set this as the accepted answer? I had trouble with this because I was using a long int, and weirdly the QVariant will work with long long int or int, but not long int. Casting my long int to qlonglong worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is far simpler than the others!

Comment: Not working with the table default sort, i.e. when trying to sort  by clicking the header arrows.

Answer (score 2):

One way that worked in my situation was

1) before filling the table, turn off sorting:

```
table.setSortingEnabled(False)
```

2) pad the number strings with blanks and make all strings in the column have the same length:

```
('    '+numStr)[-4:]
```

3) after filling the table, turn on sorting:

```
table.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

This fixed the row sorting problem and the numerical order.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the accepted answer used to work, but with Qt5.1, it doesn't.
In order to work, the `operator<` definition has to match the virtual definition from `qtablewidget.h`.

Another interesting addition is to sort items that have numbers, but start with a currency sign (`$` or `€` for instance) or end with `%`.

Here is the updated code:

```
class TableNumberItem : public QTableWidgetItem
{
public:
    TableNumberItem(const QString txt = QString("0"))
        :QTableWidgetItem(txt)
    {
    }

    bool operator < (const QTableWidgetItem &other) const
    {
        QString str1 = text();
        QString str2 = other.text();

        if (str1[0] == '$' || str1[0] == '€') {
            str1.remove(0, 1);
            str2.remove(0, 1); // we assume both items have the same format
        }

        if (str1[str1.length() - 1] == '%') {
            str1.chop(1);
            str2.chop(1); // this works for "N%" and for "N %" formatted strings
        }

        double f1 = str1.toDouble();
        double f2 = str2.toDouble();

        return str1.toDouble() < str2.toDouble();
    }
};
```

Then, you add the items that contain numbers using something like this:

```
myTableWidget->setItem(row, col, new TableNumberItem("$0"));
```

Note that this class **must** be used with numbers only, it will not sort strings correctly (as is also the case with the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and the The answer of @Chris worked for me!
but a little modification is need. I can't comment. so I write here.

```
   class MyTableWidgetItem : public QTableWidgetItem {
    public:
        bool operator <(const QTableWidgetItem &other) const
        {
            if (text()=="")
                return text().toDouble() > other.text().toDouble();
            else
                return text().toDouble() < other.text().toDouble();
        }
    };
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If `text()` is empty, then `text().toDouble()` returns -1.0 when you may be expecting 0.0 instead. You should check with that specific number instead of changing the operator. Also `other.text()` could be empty too if you expect `text()` to be empty.

Comment: I think empty cell is empty and no need to sort. it works for me for all positive number include 0.