# showing numbers in qtablewidgetitem with comma and while using the sortingenabled of qtablewidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I want to show large numbers separated by comma e.g. 123,000 not as 123000 but doing this i have to make it into a string on which the sorting is not working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to convert it to a string. Use [`locale`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#locale-prop) in order to display numbers based on user settings.

```
this->locale()->toString(value);
```

Comment: Got the commas, but setSortingEnabled(true) sorts the values in dictionary format but not as numbers.....

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848683/how-to-sort-datas-in-qtablewidget You should implement the `<` operator in order to convert to int and then compare

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier if you move to a QTableView and QStandardItemModel, rather than a QTableWidget - don't know if this is suitable for you.

Then you can specify a SortRole which is distinct from the DisplayRole.  Like this (hope the Python is readable - I use PySide)

```
    tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
    tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(3,2,self)
    model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(2):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(["1,000","200","100"][r])
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole,[1000,200,100][r])
            model.setItem(r,c,item)

    tableView.setModel(model)
```

Try commenting out the setSortRole line to see the two behaviours.