# QTableWidget setSortingEnabled on specific column Qt

Tags: qt, sorting, qtablewidget

I have a table widget that contains 2 columns. The first column contains timestamps, and the 2nd column contains the message that corresponds with the timestamp. I want the user to be able to click on the header for the timestamp column and reverse the order. I also want the user to be able to click on the message header and have all the messages be put in alphabetical order. Using setSortingEnabled works perfectly for the message header, but due to the format of the timestamp, this will not sort the timestamps correctly. Is there a way to setSortingEnabled() on just the messages column, and when the user clicks on timestamp header it calls a custom function that sorts?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848683/how-to-sort-datas-in-qtablewidget

You can subclass QTableWidgetItem and implement the < operator.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SetSortingEnabled() affects all columns.
You can setSortingEnable(False), create a function with custom sorting for the timestamp-column and standard sorting for the other columns and connect the horizonterHeaders signal sectionClicked() with this function. I tried in pyqt5, it works, but much work with recognizing the actual sortOrder, setting and deleting headerIcons etc..

A much easier way is, to set an appropriate format for the timestamp, right-aligned, fixed length, on the left filled with '0', in python3 e.g.:

```
ts = '{:0>15}'.format(timestamp)
```

left filled with spaces works too:

```
ts = '{: >15}'.format(timestamp)
```